# Android AsyncTask for Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android application I am having custom `ListView` that contains `EditText` and `Spinner`.

My problem is when I choose a `Spinner` (`spDevice`) I need to load corresponding values in another spinner (`spModel`). The problem I am facing is, when I select the value in `spDevice` its loading corresponding values in the `spModel` after some time delay, its not loading immediately (sometime data is not loading properly). I feel we have to use `AsyncTask` for this. Can anyone help me how to create `AsyncTask`for this or else can anyone tell me whats the best method to solve this issue.

Below is the code I am using now

```
private void  spDevicesetItemSelectedListener(final DeviceHolder holder){
    holder.spDevice.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

    String strDevices =(String)parent.getSelectedItem(); //Get selected value from SpDevices
    ArrayList<String> lstModels = db.getAllModels(strDevices);
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstModels);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    holder.spModel.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not needed, basically `AsyncTask` are used for long running tasks like network operations, database operations. One thing remind 'AsyncTask' are not needed for faster operations. The delay its taking is to fetch data from database, so using `AsyncTask`, it will not fasten up the loading.

Comment: sometime data is not loading properly, when I select first item in the SpDevices, its loading the corresponding values in the SpModel correctly, when I choose second item in the SpDevices instead of loading the relevant records in the second item, its loading the first item record, after sometime its loading the second item record.... so I feel the problem is in the background procesing

Comment: @SubramanianRaj No its not like that, and `AsyncTask` is not going to load faster data.

Comment: let me try and get back to you

Comment: I had solved this issue through calling AsyncTask, its working perfectly as intended. I feel in Custom ListView with more than one Spinner and the values are dependent on other Spinner, this is the best way to do. If I am wrong means correct me, I had given it as my answer

Comment: @SubramanianRaj Yup, this is the best way to do, but it will not fasten up your retrieving process, it will just run the process in the background so that your main thread just don'g get hung.

Comment: Importantly the dependent records are loading perfectly, previously it did not load properly, now its perfect. Thanks for your time :) Your suggestion gave idea to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue through calling AsyncTask, its working perfectly as intended. I feel in Custom ListView with more than one Spinner and the values are dependent on other Spinner, this is the best way to do. If I am wrong means correct me

```
if(strDevices != null && ! strDevices.isEmpty()) {
  try {
       ArrayList<String> lstModels = new LongOperation().execute(strDevices).get(); // Call Async Task
       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstModels);
       dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

       // attaching data adapter to spinner
       holder .spModel.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();;
 }
}
```